# Unable to import CSS module in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, kendo-ui

I'm trying to import

`import '@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css'`

but I get the following error:

```
Error in ./~/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css
Module not found: Cannot resolve directory '.' in C:\Users\username\work\other\react\myapp\node_modules\@progress\kendo-theme-material\dist

 @ ./~/css-loader?importLoaders=1!./~/postcss-loader!./~/@progress/kendo-theme-material/dist/all.css 6:447431-447444 6:447502-447515
```

The project is created with `npx create-react-react-app myapp`
and my node version is the 12 LTS

A strange thing is that the same demo app works on a Debian 9 System while there is an error in Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the `create-react-app` package to the latest version: `create-react-app@3.2.0`

`npm update -g create-react-app`

My version was 3.0.1

In addition I updated in the existing projects the `react-scripts` version

`npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.2.0`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/

Comment: This is relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app