# Template not provided using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

When I type the `create-react-app my-app` command in my terminal, it appears to work - downloading all libraries successfully etc. At the end of that process however I get a message that a `template was not provided`.

Input

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 Desktop% create-react-app my-app
```

Output

```
Creating a new React app in /Users/user/Desktop/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
..... nothing out of the ordinary here .....
✨  Done in 27.28s.

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
```

In package.json of `my-app`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.12.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "react-scripts": "3.3.0" <-- up-to-date
}
```

I checked out the CRA [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and it looks like support was added for custom templates - however it doesn't look like the command `create-react-app my-app` would have changed.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: rumor is that the global package isn't so hot anymore. try 'npm init react-app my-app'

Comment: Also update your install

Comment: Thanks - what ended up working (using Yarn) is upgrading CRA with: `yarn global upgrade create-react-app` - then doing `yarn create react-app my-app`

Comment: I got the same problem on a windows machine

Comment: what worked for me when all the advice here failed was doing `locate create-react-app` and deleting all directories that had `create-react-app` in the name. Only then did `npx create-react-app` finally work normally again for me.

Comment: Same here, on Windows `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` did not solve it. I had to go to the folder  `C:\Users\serge\AppData\Roaming\npm` (your path will vary), and execute `npm uninstall creat-react-app` in this folder. After that I installed with `npx create-react-app sample-react --template typescript --use-npm`.

Comment: just check the following link. It should help you https://create-react-app.dev/docs/updating-to-new-releases/

Comment: @Serge van den Oever you have solved my problem.

Answer (score 567, accepted):

> If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the latest version.

[Docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started)

Use either one of the below commands:

- `npx create-react-app my-app`
- `npm init react-app my-app`
- `yarn create react-app my-app`

**if `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` stated above does not work.**
Type `which create-react-app` to know where it is installed.  Mine was installed in `/usr/bin` folder.  Then do `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/create-react-app`. (Credit to @v42 comment below)

Comment: I thought npm uninstall -g create-react-app and npx create-react-app my-app would work. But somehow npx still creates a project without the template. Is create-react-app somehow cached? I thought having a global cra installation would be deprecated. I had to update create-react-app -g instead before using npx.

Comment: if you still have the same error after `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, enter `which create-react-app` in your console. If it returns something like `/usr/local/bin/create-react-app`, then do a `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app` to delete manually.

Comment: This is not a good approach IMHO. why do we have to be downloading and running stuff each time instead of having a local copy? Its waste of bandwidth and a very good way to execute random code from the internet and one day get hacked.... 

Just reinstall it like I did `npm install create-react-app -g` my solution means you will eventually get this error again but people *should not* be running arbitrary code from the webs and should be able to stay on a specific version if they choose so....

Comment: finally got it  to work for typescript template

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
`sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app`
`npx create-react-app newapp --template typescript`

Comment: use this `npm list -g --depth=0` to see whether create-react-app is listed in your installed node packages. If it is, run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to uninstall.

Comment: @v42 i still have same proplems I tried uninstalling global create react app and then deleted from the local manually . still I am getting the same error.

Comment: If these solutions don't work for you, it may be possible that you installed the package globally via `yarn` like I evidently did. In that case use `yarn global remove create-react-app` to remove it.

Comment: for every one on windows using `npx` to make a react app like `npx create-react-app my-app` I tried everything. Literally everything, but when I accidentally forgot to type `npx` it worked. I just typed `create-react-app my-app` and it gave me a template with no known errors!

Comment: On my MacOS 12.4, I searched in the Finder for "create-react-app" and found the react folder, and deleted everything. That seems to have worked.

Answer (score 94):

**1)**

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

or

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

**2)**

There seems to be a bug where create-react-app isn't properly uninstalled and using one of the new commands lead to:

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an
>   outdated version of create-react-app.

After uninstalling it with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, check whether you still have it "installed" with `which create-react-app` (Windows: `where create-react-app`) on your command line. If it returns something (e.g. */usr/local/bin/create-react-app*), then do a `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app` to delete manually.

**3)**

Then one of these ways:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
npm init react-app my-app
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: I had to remove the installation folder, npm uninstall create-react-app -g did not work

Comment: $ echo '#!/bin/sh' > /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
$ echo 'echo use yarn create-react-app instead' > /usr/local/bin/create-react-app $ chmod 0700 /usr/local/bin/create-react-app

Comment: On Windows, you can use the command `where` instead of `which`

Answer (score 57):

Though already lots of answer is here.
I came up with 3 solutions which I applied step by step when I faced this situation.

---

**First step:** From Official manual,

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

You can use these commands below:

- `npx create-react-app my-app`
- `npm init react-app my-app`
- `yarn create react-app my-app`

---

**Second step** (If first one doesn't work):

Sometimes it may keep caches.then you can use these commands given below.

- `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm cache verify`
- `yarn create react-app my-app`

---

**Third step:**(If these 2 won't work)
first uninstall via **`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`**,then check if you still have it "installed" with **`which create-react-app`** command on your command line. If you got something like (**/usr/local/bin/create-react-app**) then run this **`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app`** (folder may vary) to delete manually.
Then again install it via npx/npm/yarn.

**NB**: I succeed in the last step.

Comment: For whatever reason, `npx` and `npm init` did not work, but `yarn` did after clearing cache. I needed to `rm -rf` the `create-react-app` folder too. So thankful for SO.

Comment: on windows (from a wsl terminal) `which create-react-app` showed that I needed to delete the `create-react-app*` files in `/mnt/c/Users/myWindowsUser/AppData/Roaming/npm/`

Answer (score 45):

First uninstall create-react-app globally by this command:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then in your project directory:

```
npm install create-react-app@latest
```

finally:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: this one help me TY

Comment: Finally fixed this issue after about 1 year of trying. Thank you so much

Comment: Only one that worked after the dozen useless answers above, thanks!

Comment: For anyone *still* experiencing this in Oct 2022, this is the ONLY way I have managed to get it to work

Answer (score 22):

To add up more to the answers above:

With the new release of `create-react-app`, you can create a new app using custom templates.
Two templates available so far:

- cra-template
- cra-template-typescript

**Usage**:

```
npx create-react-app my-app [--template typescript]
```

More details of the latest changes in `create-react-app`:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v3.3.0

Answer (score 21):

Clear your npm cache first then use yarn as follows:

- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm cache verify`
- `yarn create react-app my-app`

I hope this helps.

***EDIT***

...you might want to try the following after I have looked into this problem further:

1. **`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`**
2. **`yarn global remove create-react-app`**
3. **`which create-react-app`** - If it returns something (e.g. /usr/local/bin/create-react-app), then do a rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app to delete manually.
4. **`npm cache clean --force`**
5. **`npm cache verify`**
6. **`npx create-react-app@latest`**

These steps should remove globally installed create-react-app installs, you then manually remove the old directories linked to the old globally installed create-react-app scripts. It's then a good idea to clear your npm cache to ensure your not using any old cached versions of create-react-app. Lastly create a new reactjs app with the **`@latest`** option like so: **`npx create-react-app@latest`**. There has been much confusion on this issue where no template is created when using npx create-react-app, if you follow the steps I have stated above (1-6) then I hope you'll have success.

p.s.

If I wanted to then create a react app in a directory called client then I would type the following command into the terminal:

`npx create-react-app@latest ./client`

Good luck.

Answer (score 20):

I too had the same problem. When I trid the `npm init react-app my-app` command returned the same message

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an
>   outdated version of create-react-app.

But

`yarn create react-app my-app` command works fine.

Answer (score 19):

1. `npm install -g create-react-app` in your pc
2. create react project again with `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: It's recommended to uninstall create-react-app globally though.

Comment: Error will return when there a new update with this method

Comment: I think this is what caused the error in the first place globally installing create-react-app

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me.

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npx create-react-app my-app`

Answer (score 15):

So I've gone through all the steps here, but non helped.

TLDR; run `npx --ignore-existing create-react-app`

I am on a Mac with `Mojave 10.15.2`

CRA was not installed globally - didn't find it in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` or `/usr/local/bin` either.

Then I came across this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8085#issuecomment-563200289) on CRA's github issues. Running the command with the `--ignore-existing` flag helped.

Comment: "npx: the --ignore-existing argument has been removed." but still, none of the answers so far fixed the issue.

Comment: I sold my mac and did a fresh install on the new one... sounds bizarre...

Answer (score 13):

`npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name`

work for me after trying all the answers hope that can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 12):

These two steps worked for me

1) Uninstalled react-app globally with this command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

2) Installed react-app in project folder with this command

```
npx create-react-app project-name
```

Answer (score 10):

"*If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version*"

This is reported at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/. For me, this did not work. I had to re-install create-react-app globally instead.

My steps to fix this problem were to:

1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
2. npm install -g create-react-app
3. npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: It's not recommended to use a global installation of create-react-app anymore.

Comment: This is true, however, I couldn't figure out another way to install the template without doing a global installation. It doesn't make a difference to my app anyway.

Answer (score 10):

All of the option didn't work for me on MacOS. What did work was the following 3 steps:

> 1. Delete the node from: /usr/local/bin/

then

> 2. install node newly: https://nodejs.org/en/

then

> 3. Install react: npx create-react-app my-app follow: https://create-react-app.dev/

Comment: Yes that is correct - then check to see if it is still installed $ react-create-app --version. IF there is still a version you may have to remove it manually.  In my case it remained ~/.nvm/versions/node/<node version>/lib/node_modules so you have to rm -rf react-create-app in that folder

Answer (score 7):

For Linux this worked for me

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-test-app
```

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: Uninstall the global package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and generate new react apps using `npx create-react-app app`.

---

#### Issue

You're using an older version of `create-react-app` that you have installed globally using npm. The `create-react-app` command invokes this global package.

You could've confirmed that you were using an outdated version by running `npm outdated -g create-react-app` or comparing `create-react-app --version` with `npm view create-react-app`.

The fact that the version of `react-scripts` was up to date, has nothing to do with the version of the package that is bootstrapping the app (`create-react-app`), which grabs the latest versions of the packages that it uses (`react-scripts` in this case).

#### Solution

If you want to continue using the `create-react-app` command, you'll need to update the global package using `npm update -g create-react-app`. Note that you'll want to do this periodically to keep it up to date. You'll notice that `create-react-app` does not recommend this (noted in the logs from your install).

A better approach would be to delete the global install entirely (`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`) and instead use `npx` so that it grabs the latest version of the package every time (more detail on `npx` below).

You should confirm that it was uninstalled globally by trying to use `create-react-app` to make sure the command is "not found".

**Issues with uninstalling?**

You can debug where it was installed using `which create-react-app`. If you're having issues uninstalling it, you may have multiple versions of node/npm on your machine (from multiple installs, or because you use a node version manager such as `nvm`). This is a separate issue I won't address here, but there's some info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47849940/4722345).

*A quick nuclear approach would be to forcefully remove it (`rm -rf`) at the path that `which create-react-app` returns.*

---

## Supplement

#### Global npm packages and the `npx` command

`$ NPM_PACKAGE_NAME` will always use the globally installed version of the package, regardless of which directory you're in.

`$ npx NPM_PACKAGE_NAME` will use the first version of the package that it finds when searching up from the current directory to the root:

- If you have the package in your current directory, it will use that.
- Else if you have the package in a directory that is a parent of your current directory, it will use the first one it finds.
- Else if you have the package installed globally, it will use that.
- Else **if you don't have the package at all, it will temporarily install it, use it, and then discard it.** - *this is the best way to ensure the package is up to date*.

More info about npx can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018825/4722345).

#### Using `npx` with `create-react-app`

`create-react-app` has some special commands/aliases to create a react app (instead of `npx`) that are specific to that package (`yarn create react-app`, `npm init react-app`), but `npx create-react-app` will work the same as it does with other packages.

#### `yarn` vs `npm` global installs

Yarn stores global installs in a different folder than `npm`, which is why `yarn create react-app` would work immediately without uninstalling the global npm package (as far as yarn is concerned, the package hasn't been installed).

This is just a temporary solution though, as you'll need to remember to always use yarn instead of npm when using Create React App.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me!

1) `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

2) `npm install -g create-react-app`

3) `npx create-react-app app_name`

> If you have any previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, Better to uninstall it using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 5):

This solved my problem

***Steps:***

1.Uninstall the create-react app

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

2.Now just use

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

this will automatically create the template for u .

Answer (score 5):

This problem is not solved like this, the problem is in the different instances of node, try removing globally create-react-app and then delete the node_modules and package-lock.json from your root user

Answer (score 4):

This work's for me :

Let's, uninstall create-react-app globally by this command:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

After that in your project directory:

```
npm install create-react-app@latest
```

At the last:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

For typescript :

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Answer (score 3):

First uninstall create-react-app

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then run `yarn create react-app my-app` or `npx create-react-app my-app`

then running `yarn create react-app my-app` or `npx create-react-app my-app` may still gives the error,

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

This may happens because of the cashes. So next run

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then run

```
npm cache verify
```

Now its all clear. Now run

`yarn create react-app my-app` or `npx create-react-app my-app`

Now you will get what you expected!

Answer (score 3):

I fix this issue on **Mac** by uninstalling `create-react-app` from global npm lib, that's basically what said, just try to do, you need also do `sudo`:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Then simply run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app-name
```

Now should be all good and get the folder structures as below:

[image: template not provided using create react app]

Comment: I was trying all these writed above methods on Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu based system).  Nothing helped, but this did it. `sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Answer (score 3):

Using the command `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` didn't work for me.

But this worked:

`yarn global remove create-react-app`

and then:

`npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: This worked for me, I tried every methods including manual delete from /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 2):

Such a weird problem because this worked for me yesterday and I came across the same error this morning. Based on the release notes, a new feature was added to support templates so it looks like a few parts have changed in the command line (for example, the `--typescript` was deprecated in favor of using `--template typescript`)

I did manage to get it all working by doing the following:

1. Uninstall global create-react-app `npm uninstall create-react-app -g`.
2. Verify npm cache `npm cache verify`.
3. Close terminal. I use the mac terminal, if using an IDE maybe close and re-open.
4. Re-open terminal, browse to where you want your project and run create-react-app via npx using the new template command conventions. For getting it to work, I used the typescript my-app from the documentation site to ensure consistency: `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`

If it works, you should see multiple installs: one for react-scripts and one for the template. The error message should also no longer appear.

Answer (score 2):

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app` could be an answer in some cases, but not in mine.

You should manually delete your create-react-app located at `~/.node/bin/` or `/usr/bin/` (just type `which create-react-app` and remove it from locations you saw using `rm -rf`), next just run `npm i -g create-react-app`.

After that `create-react-app` will be working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me
1.First uninstall create-react-app globally by this command:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

If there you still have the previous installation please delete the folder called my app completely.(Make sure no program is using that folder including your terminal or cmd promt)

2.then in your project directory:

```
npm install create-react-app@latest
```

3.finally:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 2):

For any Windows users still having this issue, this is what fixed it for me:

1. Run `where create-react-app` to get the path (mine was in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin).
2. Navigate to that directory and delete both "create-react-app" and "create-react-app.cmd".
3. Navigate to the directory you want to start a project in.
4. Run `npm install create-react-app`,
   `npx create-react-app name-of-app`,
   `cd name-of-app`, `yarn start`.

Step #4 will vary based on your configuration, but that's just what got me up and running.

Comment: Can confirm. Deleting just the "create-react-app" doesn't fix it, but deleting both that and "create-react-app.cmd" did.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to do it is by using

```
npx --ignore-existing create-react-app [project name]
```

This will remove the old cached version of create-react-app and then get the new version to create the project.

**Note:** Adding the name of the project is important as just ignoring the existing **create-react-app** version is stale and the changes in your machines global env is temporary and hence later just using `npx create-react-app [project name]` will not provide the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

```
npx create-react-app@latest {project name}
```

this seems to be the way to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The below steps worked for me

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npx clear-npx-cache`
3. `npm i -g create-react-app`
4. `create-react-app myapp`

Comment: Please do not abuse bold formatting. It's code, so just format it as such please.

Answer (score 1):

After using this command:

```
yarn global upgrade create-react-app
```

I then tried:

```
yarn create-react-app my-app but it didn't work for me.
```

This worked though:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 I had to manually delete some folders in yarn's cache, my path was something like `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v1` and the foldes I had to remove were something like `npm-create-react-app-1.0.0-1234567890abcdef`

Comment: For Windows 7 this also solved my issue. One I deleted the Yarn cache and ran `npm cache clear --force`, etc I was able to run `npx create react app`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the following command.

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

`npm cache clean --force`

then

`npx create-react-app project_name --template all`

Thanks for this! Worked for me too.

Comment: Still got some error "A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app" even after those step. Wonder, shouldn't be Typescript the "template"?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem & i have installed "create-react-app" globally on my machine. 
There is error :

> "A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
>   Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported."

Then i removed previous install by using this command.

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

Then install new react app.

> npx create-react-app new-app

Answer (score 0):

Try running your terminal as an administrator. I was having the same issue and nothing helped apart from opening the terminal as administrator and then doing the npx create-react-app yourAppName

Answer (score 0):

FOR UBUNTU: in case you are  having an error that a template is not provided with `npx create-react-app` and already unistalled `npm create-react-app -g` and still doesn't work, do the following:

```
sudo rm -rf usr/bin/create-react-app    

# this will manualy remove the create-react-app. 
npx create-react-app
```

either with typescript works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error 'Template not provided ...." again and again, then straigt away do the followiong to steps:

1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
2. check the location of your file 'create-react-app' by using the command "which create-react-app"
3. Now manually delete that file using the command "rm -rf /usr/local/bin/create-react-app" replacing this command with the exact path shown in the previous step.
4. Finally run 'npx create-react-app '

This will replace your old file 'create-react-app' which is causing the problem with the new file downloaded with npx.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in last week. I tried many things that is provided in this answer section. But now this thing is different. Latest version of this create-react-app provided 2 templates.

**1. cra-template**

**2. cra-template-typescript**

If you use javascript, choose cra-template. And if you use typescript, use cra-template-typescript.

First you have to uninstall the create-react-app. (If you have the latest version, ignore this step.)

```
 npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Again install the latest version of the create-react-app

```
npm install create-react-app@latest
```

Now you have to import the template like this. (If you use typescript, use "cra-template-typescript" instead of "cra-template". my-app is used as a name. you can give it any name).

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template
```

Now the template will be downloaded. But remind in your mind, this is not equal to the past versions. (something different)

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred because there is global installs of `create-react-app` are no longer supported. For solving this problem, you should uninstall and remove completely `create-react-app` from your system, so  run these command respectively:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

or

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

Then please check if the create-react-app exists or not with this command

```
which create-react-app
```

If it returns any correct path like a

```
/c/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin/create-react-app
```

Then run this command to remove `create-react-app` globally

```
rm -rf /c/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/Yarn/bin/create-react-app
```

Now you can create a new react app with one of these commands:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
npm init react-app my-app
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: Those steps worked, so one need also to remove the local files of create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

**please try this:**

> npx create-react-app project-name --template all

Answer (score 0):

If other answers are not helping and especially if you recently moved to Big Sur, this may be helpful.

I tried all of the steps described in all answers, but could not get CRA to generate a template for me. It may have been due to the fact that I recently moved to Big Sur, and had not updated node/npm etc. The create-react-app binary was not installed (neither in /usr/bin nor in /usr/local/bin), but anytime I would run `npx create-react-app project` it would end with the dreaded "A template was not provided.." message. I upgraded node and npm, tried removing create-react-app using both npm and yarn, cleared the npm cache, tried using `npm react-app project`, all to no avail.

Whenever I would run these commands, it would start with complaining about react-scripts using outdated packages:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.22.10
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning react-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintain
<etc. - tons of warnings like these>
```

So I suspected that maybe `react-scripts` was the problem. To check, I ran `npm list`. To my surprise, CRA was listed as one of the "extraneous" packages:

```
├── create-react-app@1.5.2 extraneous
```

I then ran `npm uninstall create-react-app@1.5.2`, which worked. And the next invocation of `npx create-react-app project` prompted me that CRA would be installed. Sure enough, the installation worked and a template was indeed used.

Hope this helps anyone stuck in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

if nothing above works ..
use this `npx clear-npx-cache`
then `npx create-react-app my-app`
hope it will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing of the above worked for you this is what I did:
On ubuntu (and probably mac and windows) **search for the node_modules folder** and manualy delete the create-react-app module, update the package.json and package-lock.json and run again

```
npx create-react-app <app-name>
```

works!

Answer (score 0):

No one mentioned the most basic problem but,
Windows users.
Make sure you update your node version.
None of the answers worked for me until I updated my node.js

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33570352)