# use create-react-app and don't have any folder

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npm-start

I want to create a new app with react js and when I create an app, I don't have any folder (src, public) and when  I start project get this error
npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template not provided using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this steps

1. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
2. npm cache clean --force
3. npm i create-react-app -g
4. npx create-react-app my-app