# React install will not run despite changing permissions?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have run create-react-app in the past couple months, without event. This time however, it appeared to run like normal (see screenshot 1 below), but when I went to npm start it said there was no template. I googled the error & it said that there was a new version of create-react-app & that npm -g create-react-app was no longer supported. I landed on [this stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app) which said that I had to uninstall in order to run 'npx create-react-app my-app' & get the current version. That threw an error that I didn't have permissions. Node modules was assigned to the root, not me the user. So I googled how to change the permission & [landed on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules-react) When I ran 'sudo chown -R MYUSERNAME: /usr/local/lib/node_modules' it changed 3 of 4 node modules folders from 'root' to me. See the 3rd screenshot in the image below. I tried to, at this point run 'npx create-react-app my-app'. It did its thing, but when I try to 'npm start' it throws a new error (see screenshot 2 below). When I follow the debug log I get screenshot 4 below. I am at my wits end here. Let me know what I'm missing. I thought I changed the permissions so I could clear it, but it says I didn't. I feel like I'm losing my mind here.

[image: This is what happens when I run create-react-app & what happens when I run it, & a permissions log]

Comment: Can we see your `package.json`?

Comment: i think you are out of your project folder i.e.command not found package.json file Or run your cmd as an adminstrator

Comment: Tim here you go: {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  }
}

Comment: PRADIP GORULE I ran the install the same way I've run it in the past. Usually I run create-react-app, then I go into the folder, then run npm start. This time it's not working.