# I cannot create react app using the instructions provided

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I've tried every answer in this thread: [Template not provided using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app)

Nothing has worked. A lot of people had luck after the which creare-react-app but I get nothing.

Here's the steps I did along with screen shot to show the steps I followed.

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- npm cache clean --force
- npm cache verify
- which create-react-app
- rm -rf the directory provided from the which c-r-a (see photo)
- npx create-react-app bluegrass-doodles

All I get is a yarn-error in my folder.

Thanks. [Code up to rm -rf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49374.png)

[Shows what I get after npx create-react-app bluegrass-doodles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ex2wP.png)

Comment: you are cleaning npm cache but looks like `create-react-app` were installed using `yarn`.  try to remove with `yarn global remove create-react-app` ant then clean yarn's cache with `yarn cache clean` , see https://next.yarnpkg.com/cli/cache/clean

Comment: This worked! Thank you @ConradoFonseca

Answer (score 0):

seams resolve/.yarn-metadata.json is not well formatted.

maybe this can help

- update npm
- update yarn
- update local node

I hope this can help you