# How do I solve problem creating react app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I tried to create react app with `npx create-react-app projectreact`. It gave me following error:

```
PS C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Reaact JS> npx create-react-app projectreact

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Reaact JS\projectreact.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Reaact JS\projectreact\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Reaact JS\projectreact\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\ahnaa\OneDrive\Documents\Web Developent\Reaact JS\projectreact\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react@16.13.1
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1625 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1629 packages in 531.566s

59 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Template not provided using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app)

Comment: i did `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` but same things happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then try running

```
npx create-react-app projectreact
```