# Create React App Folders Not Being Installed Properly Upon using NPX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npx

Running into this error below when using npx create-react-app

> ```
> Husna@LAPTOP-LPCC954R MINGW64 ~/Desktop/React GitHib Project (master)
> $ npx create-react-app github2020
>
> Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Husna\Desktop\React GitHib Project\github2020.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
>
>
> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Husna\Desktop\React GitHib Project\github2020\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
>
> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Husna\Desktop\React GitHib Project\github2020\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Husna\Desktop\React GitHib Project\github2020\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> + react-dom@16.13.1
> + react-scripts@3.4.1
> + react@16.13.1
> added 1601 packages from 751 contributors and audited 1605 packages in 869.821s
>
> 59 packages are looking for funding
>  run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 4981 low severity vulnerabilities
>  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
>
> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
> Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Template not provided using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app) While some of the answers suggest running the command you just ran, they also provide solutions for when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, npx sometimes create issues for me to if you have already install yarn then try to create your react app through it.

In case you don't have yarn already.

you can install yarn through `npm i -g yarn`

and then you can just create your react app directly without using npx

`create-react-app github2020`

Comment: hey do you know how to  remove the create-react-app manually because its still giving me the error

Comment: you can run this command to remove globally in your system 
**npm uninstall -g create-react-app**
and please let me know whats the error you are getting while creating