# when i try to create react app ,i get " template was not provided ,This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app " Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

when i try to install react app  with following code

```
npx create-react-app app1
```

i get following problem

```
 A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

i tried `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and still it gives the same error , i don't know where the issue lies.

my system info

```
os : Windows 10 64 bit 
nodeJs  : v14.15.0
npm  : v6.14.8
```

is this a problem with the node version..? How to solve the issues

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app

Comment: Thanks, It solved With " npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name " this code

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove create-react-app from node_modules from user root
and `npx create-react-app myapp` should work.

or

`npx --ignore-existing create-react-app`

Comment: Thanx for the help,"  npx create-react-app@latest your-project-name  "   this code solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

I searched for create-react-app on my whole mac through finder and deleted that folder. Then it worked

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that there is no file named create-react-app anywhere:
You can use: `where create-react-app` in windows to locate it, if that doesn't work, search for it in the file explorer and delete it, that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Implement the following steps:
Write this code into your editor:
`npm install --global yarn` 
And then upgrade:
`yarn global upgrade` 
Create your app. You can choose your app name:
`yarn create react-app your-app-name` 
Go to your app directory:
`cd your-app-name`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Delete the folder with the title create-react-app from your machine then
npx create-react-app my-app
this must fix your problem...