# My terminal is throwing me errors when i create-react-app that says my create-react-app is outdated but I cannot update or unistall it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Full disclosure I am brand new to React.
[this is the original response I get when I tried to create-react-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDfTJ.png)

[I tried to uninstall react-scripts and create-react-app but was given these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haw4T.png)

I was following a video tutorial and In the beginning I wrote "sudo -g create-react-app@1.5.2". Then i ran create-react-app first-app. In the video the guy was shown all the different npm explanations but I got these back. How do I clear this up so I can create the app successfully?

Comment: have u tried uninstalling using sudo ```sudo npm uninstall create-react-app -g``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar post to yours and contains the required information to fix your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59189242/10746940

Comment: thank you! I am getting another error saying that the directory contains files that could conflict: node_modules/, package-lock.json, package.son. How would I go about uninstalling those?

Comment: You can delete node_modules and run `npm install` again. If you have more copies of package-lock.json and packge.json delete the oldest verison, if not dont. Please mark my answer as correct so that others might benefit aswell. :)