# npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I tried running:

```sh
npm install -g create-react-app
```

the following error occurred:

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 2s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I've looked at the solution proposed in [npm-warn-deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68857411/npm-warn-deprecated-tar2-2-2-this-version-of-tar-is-no-longer-supported-and-w), I installed tar using `npm i tar` and other methods but the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Node >= 14.0.0 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine. To create a project, execute:

```
npx create-react-app create-react-app 
cd create-react-app 
npm start
```

The npx in the first line is not a misspelling-it is the package running tool that comes with npm 5.2+