# I couldn´t install react with npx create-react-app my-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to use npx create-react app but i have errors that is shown below:

```
 npm ERR! could not determine executable to run

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR! C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-08T13_57_59_084Z-debug-0.log
```

I had this error after using a command in my windows terminal:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

It throws:

```
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 67 packages, and audited 69 packages in 15s

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a similar issue to this question: [npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68857411/npm-warn-deprecated-tar2-2-2-this-version-of-tar-is-no-longer-supported-and-w)

The accepted answer was to update tar using the command **npm i tar**