# I can't create new app with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command-line

I can't fix it no matter what. I have reinstalled node.js probably 8 times. When I google, everyone says run this command `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. It didn't get fixed tho. It gives the same problem again and again. I tried `npm audit fix --force` and every one time it just finds more than 100 vulnerabilities and fixes them again (decreases to 0). I don't know what to do.
[image: node.js screenshot]

Comment: do you have the `node_modules` folder or `package.json` in `C:\Users\yusif`?

Comment: what does this return `npm -v create-react-app`

Comment: npm cache clean --force

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app

Comment: Yes, Amir, I have both of them. node_modules and package.json. Although I don't know which package.json are u talking about. In node_modules folder or separated of that?

Comment: npm version is 8.1.2. Up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. After trying many techniques, I somehow got it.

```
npx --ignore-existing create-react-app
npx create-react-app@latest
```

That worked for me:

```
npm uninstall create-react-app
npm update
```