# Templete was not provided using create create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, create-react-app

when I try to install react via `npx create-react-app my-app` it is showing me the error that "A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again." Even after I have uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and cheeked via `which create-react-app` and found their was no previous package is install , but still I am facing this issue .
Any idea what going on here?
[look at screenshot provided for more  info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUDNe.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app

Comment: To save you reading all that: `npx create-react-app@latest my-app` will most likely work. I removed global CRA from my system and it still came up with that error. Adding `@latest`  was the only thing that did the trick.

Comment: I have  tried this but it is showing me the same error.