# Why create-react-app don't create the body of the app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I wanted to create a **react** application using **npx create-react-app my-app**, it runs and create a folder with node_modules, package.json and yarn.lock without the src and the public folder and it returns **a template was not provided, this is likely you're using an outdated version of create-react-app** like y'all seeing in the screenshots.

**node v16.15.1, npm v7.24.2**

[this this commands i used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtQZu.jpg)

[and this is the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXy7g.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution for this.
I just needed to delete create-react-app folder in the node_modules because the uninstall command didn't work and run this command
**npm install create-react-app@latest**
then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the command that is written in the last line: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`? And then try again with `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: Yes i did, and it didn't fix the problem

Comment: @Guetatlouay you could try some solutions from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app