# Why does npx create-react-app give a code 127 error?

Tags: node.js

I've tried so many solutions online, but I haven't seen how to resolve the code 127 error Attached is the error: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIqf.png)

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Delete your npm-cache folders in AppData/Roaming, especially if you recently updated your Node.js and npm versions. Then you should be able to run npx create-react-app!